# Google Apps Script with ExtJS 4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, google-apps-script, google-caja

Q: Is it possible to add ExtJS 4 in Caja templates in any way?

For example, when writing load instructions to the HTML header:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   document.write("\x3Cscript type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/ext-all.js'>\x3C/script>");
 </script>
```

Results in something like this:

```
Invalid script or HTML content: http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+6635 - 6636: Expected <Identifier> not : http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+6621 - 6652: Skipping malformed content http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+6621 - 6672: Skipping malformed content http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+82707 - 82708: Expected <Identifier> not : http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+82677 - 82724: Skipping malformed content http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+82677 - 82744: Skipping malformed content http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+111019 - 111020: Expected <Identifier> not : http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+111002 - 111036: Skipping malformed content http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+111051 - 111052: Expected <Identifier> not : http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+111037 - 111068: Skipping malformed content http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+111002 - 111088: Skipping malformed content http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+200996 - 200997: Expected <Identifier> not : http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+200982 - 201013: Skipping malformed content http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+200982 - 201033: Skipping malformed content http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+217948 - 217949: Expected <Identifier> not : http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+217931 - 217965: Skipping malformed content http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+217931 - 217985: Skipping malformed content http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+219058 - 219075: Not a valid uri: 'url(#default#VML)' http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1a-commercial/resources/css/ext-all.css:18+219049 - 219075: Skipping malformed content HtmlOutput:11+132 - 12+1: Unclosed string.
```

Just noticed the Caja validation-errors are related to the CSS, but while the Ext object can't be constructed - this makes no difference. As it seems only jQuery and jQueryUI available as precajoles: [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/third_party/?r=5046#third_party/precajole). If jqGrid would at least work, this might be an alternative (but since I intend to use ExtJS, I'd rather just switch the environment to something a little more compatible).

That Maestro HTML-app just says: 'Failed to load ext-all.js'. Haven't tried to include the lib "locally" on the Drive - but I'd guess like this the same castration of JS might be applied.

Security for embedding 3rd party scripts is no bad idea in general -

But if security features cannot be overridden - it's hindering innovation.

Probably should just assume it's not supported and move on;
just have nothing left for such proprietary solutions -
they might build their very own internet, but without me.

Comment: Can you post the html that you're using to include the scripts/stylesheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on Caja. I haven't looked at ExtJS in particular, but the usual cause of trouble for a new JS framework is that there's some little feature or corner case that Caja doesn't accurately implement. The web platform is massive, and we must prioritize functionality which people expect to use, as saying “implement everything before you continue” is impractical.

I recommend that you [file an enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/entry) to support ExtJS. It would be especially helpful would be if you were to examine ExtJS's CSS and determine what part of it Caja is rejecting (e.g. by comparing the error to line numbers in an unminified version, or if necessary, deleting parts until it is not rejected) so that we can focus on adding the necessary features.

---

Note that you should not expect `document.write`ing a `<script>` element to work; dynamically defined scripts are in general not available in the current deployment of Caja in Google Apps Script. Use a literal `<script>` element in the HTML instead. This is likely why you see only errors related to the CSS and neither success nor an error on ExtJS itself. (I've just recorded that [we ought to give an error message in this case](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1652).)

Comment: I assume the main problem are the compass-compiled themes with the @ tags - and that Caja always tries to provide the topmost framework.
Most likely I'm not the only one who'd like to see this feature become reality - but probably the way Caja and ExtJS work cannot be fully combined (which is certainly more limiting than useful). Would be great if Google could provide any trusted CDN, which would allow certain overrides. Meanwhile I'll try to get jgGrid running - simply because I'd require a data-grid - and not a spreadsheet. Will accept your answer, because the explanation already helps.

Comment: For me it's understandable that basic functionality is way more important than 3rd party support. But please checkout the components it provides once: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples -
as you can see it's all very business-application related.

Comment: @syslogic It's not a matter of “trusting” — all code you load, including things like jQuery, is in the same environment. We simply haven't got a 100% accurate emulation of what a browser does outside of Caja — we'd like to, but we're not there yet. “Business applications” aren't the issue; it's just that you're the first person (I've heard) to ask for ExtJS. Nearly everyone wants to run jQuery; some would like to run Angular, or Prototype; and so on. I really recommend you make a request on our issue tracker to look at ExtJS, as I described above; it will help determine our priorities.

Comment: If I'm really the first one asking, assumable nobody imagined the potential yet which that framework might provide. Currently I just can run things off a web-server and export to gSheet over the Drive API... but I'm rather after integrated solutions, not that distributed ones. In ExtJS there is even an adapter to plugin jQuery.